# Crontab doesnt run python script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, cron

I have the following issue: my 'hello world' python script can't be run by crontab.

If I set crontab instruction like this:

`* * * * * cd /home/ && /usr/bin/python /home/hello.py`

Text doesn't appear in terminal.

But if I do:

```
* * * * * cd /home/ && /usr/bin/python /home/hello.py >> /home/log.txt
```

Ubuntu appends 'hello world' text to log.txt

here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print('Hello World!')
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. already read this topic [Why crontab scripts are not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working/24527)

Comment: You should set terminal and display. Please read this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/309892/550618

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting output from a cron job on the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309853/getting-output-from-a-cron-job-on-the-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

Your script is executed by Cron and everything works as it is expected. Just Cron isn't designed to output anything into a terminal. So, IMO, the correct question here should be something like: **Where the standard output goes within Cron?**

Unless it is redirected (`>`, `>>`) or piped (`|`) to another program, everything that usually will be outputted to the [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) (if you are execute a command in the command-line), including all error messages, will be sent to the local mailbox of the user that runs the Cronjob. To send/receive these emails you should apply a minimal configuration as it is described here: **[How do I set Cron to send emails?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1020965/566421)**

Most of the suggestions in the [proposed duplication](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309853/getting-output-from-a-cron-job-on-the-terminal/309892#309892) explain how to redirect the output of a Cronjob to TTY or terminal window, but to get the output there you should be login (in that TTY or terminal window) in advance. Here are few additional examples:

- [Three ways to get output from Crontab](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018301/566421)
- [Where is the default place of Cronjobs execution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011260/566421)
- [Cron job to run python script at reboot does not work](https://askubuntu.com/q/970771/566421)
- [Crontab and program that should be executed into a terminal window](https://askubuntu.com/q/955582/5664210)
- [How to launch any GUI related application from Crontab in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/978413/566421)
- [Adjust brightness with xrandr and cron job](https://askubuntu.com/q/958228/566421)

---

In addition, in this case:

- `cd /home/` is not needed because your script doesn't write anything there, and the script is called by its full path.
- `/usr/bin/python` is not neede, because you tell the system that is Python script by the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`. But in this case the file should have executable permissions: `chmod +x /home/hello.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```
* * * * * cd /home/ && /usr/bin/python /home/hello.py >> /dev/tty3
```

(or your tty, if not tty3)

Comment: The user should be login that tty first. Otherwise we go back to the question - where goes STDOUT within Cron? :)