# How to set crontab for python script daily for 3 times a day for in a week for all 7 days?

Tags: 18.04, cron

I tried the solution:

1. [Crontab doesnt run python script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021622/crontab-doesnt-run-python-script)

but did not worked:

Thanks in advance,

I want that script to be executed at around 08:00, 15:00 and 18:00 IST

Answer (score 0):

I had the solution which was answered by another question of mine.

1. [How to schedule a cronjob for python script to be executed on weekdays?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236586/how-to-schedule-a-cronjob-for-python-script-to-be-executed-on-weekdays#1236586)

   `0 8,15,18 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/python3 /home/[username]/Documents/Python/script.py`